# plt.imshow(np.squeeze(x_train[3]), cmap="gray"); what does this command mean?

Tags: python

I was working on the classification of images. I came across this one line and I'm not able to figure the meaning.

```py
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(x_train[3]), cmap=“gray”);
```

Could you explain this line to me?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what your variable `x_train` contains. You give no context to your code. I can infer that `x_train` is a numpy array that is indexed at the fourth element or row.

`plt.imshow` is a function from the matplotlib library which accepts an array that represents an image and draws that to the screen. The array is usually either a 2D-array representing rows and columns of pixels or a 3D-array, where every pixel is characterized by either 3 values for RGB or 4 values for RGBA (A stands for alpha and indicates the transparency).

The `cmap="gray"` is a keyword argument passed to `plt.imshow`, which is responsible for mapping a specific colormap to the values found in the array that you passed as the first argument. You can look up the colormap if you google matplotlib colormaps.
Since the gray colormap is used in your code, it is very likely that your array is a 2D-array that represents a grayscale image. In that case, every pixel is only described by one value (usually between 0 and 255) that indicates its color on a scale from black (0) to white (255).
If you pass a 3D-array (so a color image) to imshow, matplotlib will automatically interpret the values in the third dimension as RGB values and correctly show the image.
If you however pass a 2D-array, which is probably the case, matplotlib will map the values to a colormap, which is "viridis" by default. This will result in a green / yellow / blue image. Therefore, it is necessary to tell matplotlib to map it to a grayscale colormap.

I assume that `x_train` is therefore a numpy array with more than two dimensions that probably contains multiple images. When you index it at the index 3, you obtain a part of the array that holds the values for the image you want to display. This array seems to have more dimensions than are really in use, which is why `np.squeeze` is used to reduce the unnecessary dimensions. As an example:

```
import numpy as np
test_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
np.squeeze(test_array)
>>> array([1, 2, 3])
```

This is all I can tell you from the little information you've given. Next time consider providing more context to your question.